ValueError: The filepath provided must end in `.keras` (Keras model format). Received: filepath=model/keypoint_classifier/keypoint_classifier.hdf5
PYTHON version : 3.12.4
PIP version : 24.1.1
KERAS version : 3.4.1
TENSORFLOW version : 2.16.1
i've been trying to run a code on jupyter notebook in order to train a model:
which actually throws an error:
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[10], line 2
      1 # Model chekpoint Callback
----> 2 cp_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
      3     model_save_path, verbose=1, save_weights_only=False)
      4 # Callback for early Termination
      5 es_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(patience=20, verbose=1)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\callbacks\model_checkpoint.py:191, in ModelCheckpoint.__init__(self, filepath, monitor, verbose, save_best_only, save_weights_only, mode, save_freq, initial_value_threshold)
    189 else:
    190     if not self.filepath.endswith(".keras"):
--> 191         raise ValueError(
    192             "The filepath provided must end in `.keras` "
    193             "(Keras model format). Received: "
    194             f"filepath={self.filepath}"
    195         )

ValueError: The filepath provided must end in `.keras` (Keras model format). Received: filepath=model/keypoint_classifier/keypoint_classifier.hdf5

CODE:
# Model chekpoint Callback
cp_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
    model_save_path, verbose=1, save_weights_only=False)
# Callback for early Termination
es_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(patience=20, verbose=1)


What is your question? The error tells you what to do, did you try it?

@Dr.Snoopy Sir, my question is that earlier it used to work with .h5 format which can potentially be imported by matlab also. So why suddenly .h5 is not being supported. I don't know if .keras can also be imported by matlab.

It is not sudden, Keras 3 only supports .keras models, versions < 3 still support .h5, and this was announced lots of time ago.

I see save_weights_only=False so append .keras to model_save_path, then it will work.
I had a similar issues in my model, appending .keras to file path solved the issue.
